# What is the in-universe term for Muggles in other countries?

Tags: harry-potter, muggles, terminology

Muggles, as we know, are the people who have no magical ability and are born in a non-magical family. Non-magical people are called Muggles in the British magical community and 'No-maj' in the American community. But we can find wizards in other countries also. E.g the twins Parvati and Padma Patil were of Indian descent.

What are non-magical people called by magical communities outside of Britain and America?

I am not asking about different languages like German or French. I am asking about different magical communities in other countries.

Comment: In Germany maybe it’s die Mügglen?

Comment: Rowling is incorrect; in America we have always referred to them as _Muggles_ as well. Not sure where she gets her information.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard so you're saying that the one who created the HP universe is wrong? *from where she gets her information* -- I loved this part

Comment: In the books? (i.e. Harry sees a "non-magician" in Spain, how will he call it ?) or in real life (If I buy Harry Potter in Spain, how will muggles be translated) ?

Comment: @Goufalite In the spanish books, it's the same: *"muggles"*  (lowercase, usually italicized) (pronunciado "maguels"). Example of use (not actual sentences from the books): "¿Siempre has vivido rodeado de *muggles*, Harry?" ("Have you always lived surrounded by muggles, Harry?"). "La madre de Hermione es una *muggle*" ("Hermione's mother is a muggle")

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Same place she gets her American history?

Comment: Is your question about what Indians (for example) **IN** the Harry Potter universe would call muggles or how it is translated into Hindi? Some answers seem to assume the former question, while others answer the latter. You might want to clarify this in the question.

Comment: @JAD What Indians or French call Muggles.

Comment: @Shreedhar  [](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/whoosh-you-missed-the-joke)

Comment: In Dutch, the translation of Muggle is "Dreuzel". Why do you believe there'd be a difference between translating this term as it applies to England and the description of the Dutch no-maj community?

Answer (score 19):

As far as the information from the HP books (and movies), Fantastic Beasts first movie, and as you mentioned in your question, the non-wizarding world people are addressed as:

1. ***MUGGLES*** by the British community
2. ***NO-MAJ (NON-MAGICALS)*** by the American community

However, according to David Yates (director of the new Fantastic Beasts movie), in his interview [here](http://ew.com/movies/2018/01/18/fantastic-beasts-french-muggle/), he mentioned that the French address non-wizards as:

> ***NON-MAGIQUES***

Which is undoubtedly the literal translation of the American term. However, as far as I have read, searched and seen online, these are the only three terms mentioned. (*Fingers crossed for some new reveals though!*)

Comment: I really hope they won't use that word, when the translator actually succeeded in coming with a decent name, "Moldus". Even though I can't really see how they could use it in English.

Comment: @Vrashnak I know right. It's weird that they were lazy enough to just translate it.

Comment: One could say the very word "No-Maj" was already quite lazy... But well.

Comment: Moldu(s) is the French word for it (i'm French). All the French translated movies of Harry Potter use this word (didn't see Fantastic Beasts).

Comment: @Goufalite i'm quite fluent in French too. you're referring to the *translated* words. The question is about the actual terms in other languages and regions. For example: In English itself, the Americans use Non-mag while Brits go for Muggles - One language, different terms.

Comment: Are those terms for use  in-universe? In the US, I don't think I've ever heard "non-mag"... It's always "Muggle".

Comment: @Goufalite except that the Fantastic Beast series is making up new terms for muggles, like No-maj (USA).  The American books clearly stated "Muggle", but it was changed for the first Fantastic Beasts movie.  According to sources, they've made up a new name for Muggles distinct to the one found in the French translation of the books

Comment: I hate to say this, as the bold, italicized text makes you seem quite confident in your answer, but the American term is *no-maj* not *non-mag*.

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes, in-universe, though typoed - the term No-Maj was introduced in [the Fantastic Beasts movie from 2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantastic_Beasts_and_Where_to_Find_Them_(film)), which is set in the US

Comment: Do wizards really *address* non-wizards with these terms?  I thought the terms were used only to *refer* to non-wizards.

Comment: As an American, I object to Rowling’s attempt at Americanism. Obviously we would use an acronym. We love acronyms. Especially TLAs (three letter acronyms).

Comment: Agreed with @sgroves, this answer contains inaccuracies.

Comment: @GhotiandChips could you point out the inaccuracies? (Except the no-maj non-mag one; I already corrected that).

Comment: If you fixed the inaccuracies (after I made the observation), then there are no more inaccuracies to speak of.

Comment: @GhotiandChips apologies my friend but when you said inaccuracies, I thought there were more than one. Its better to be sure; that's why I asked your help. Anyways, thanks for pointing it out. :)

Answer (score 14):

Even though only two words have been officially disclosed, we could assume other countries would use the words introduced in official translations of HP books. There's a list of translations for "muggle" at [Harry Potter Wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_wizarding_terms_in_translations_of_Harry_Potter#Muggle).

Comment: Thats a reasonable assumption. Has JKR said anything about this?

Comment: The American version uses "Muggle" and the French translation uses "Moldu". I don't think this assumption will hold.

Comment: This list provides the *translated/dubbed* names in movies in various languages, not the actual terms.

Answer (score 2):

I dont believe Rowling has answered this. I suspect we might find out what muggles in France are called with the next Fantastic Beasts movie.

Comment: Are you sure this hasn't been answered on Pottermore or elsewhere?

Comment: **In France we say "Moldu(s)"** (source : I'm French). I didn't dig why because I don't know if OP wants a list or a canon explaination of "muggle" ethymology in the potterverse...

Answer (score 2):

In the Finnish translations, it is **Jästi**. The source is a currently unavailable *pro gradu* work for Tampere University linguistics:

http://uta32-kk.lib.helsinki.fi/bitstream/handle/10024/90829/gradu00230.pdf
(gives a timeout error at the moment)

> Hanna Karppinen: 
>   Harry Potter -kirjojen suomennoksissa käytetyt uudissanat,
>   Appendix 2. Pro gradu. Tampereen yliopisto, 2003

Translation: "The neologisms used in translations of the Harry Potter books"

Funnily enough, the word means a person that is an outsider. One that does not belong to any circles. It can be any kind of a circle, ie. a group of people with a common interest or background.

The word itself was selected by the Finnish translator, Jaana Kapari, from the word **jästipää** which means a very stubborn person. Stubborn to a level of stupidity.

[https://fi.wiktionary.org/wiki/jästi](https://fi.wiktionary.org/wiki/j%C3%A4sti)

Btw, the English version of that page tells that it's a person who does not partake in geocaching, but that seems to be someone's joke addition :)

Answer (score 1):

In India, they're called **"मगलू"** in Hindi which in English would be pronounced as **"Mugloo"**.

Source: [glosbe.com/en/hi/Muggle](http://glosbe.com/en/hi/Muggle) and also from [Harry Potter Wikia](http://harrypotter.answers.wikia.com/wiki/Muggle_in_hindi). For the pronounciation part, you can copy paste the Hindi word in the translator and listen to the audio

Comment: Do you have any references to support this? Preferably from HP universe?

Comment: https://glosbe.com/en/hi/Muggle and this is from Harry Potter Wikia : http://harrypotter.answers.wikia.com/wiki/Muggle_in_hindi For the pronounciation part, you can copy paste the Hindi word in the translator and listen to the audio.

Comment: I have watched all HP movies in both Hindi and English, so I can confirm this word is right.

Comment: @Abhi Good to know. You can [edit] your answer and add those references in your answer directly instead of comments.

Comment: That first link is definitely an out-of-universe translation, the second is a single word on a *wiki*. Hardly references if you ask me.

Comment: @JAD What do you mean by "out-of-universe" translation? I know these aren't good sources but since these words sprung up from the mind of an English literature professor in India (Dr. Sudhir), good luck finding authentic references for the same. Rowling has had nothing to do with these translations and understandably so. https://www.quora.com/Who-translated-Harry-Potter-novels-in-Hindi        Let me tell you, Hindi isn't very popular even in India when it comes to HP books (movies, maybe yeah). I personally prefer English for both books and movies as it feels more authentic.

Comment: @Abhi So the books predominantly use the english word "Muggle". The Hindi books translate that to मगलू, but that doesn't mean that "Indian wizards" would actually call muggles मगलू. The distinction between in- and out-of-universe is whether it is what the translator came up with, or whether there are actually Indian wizards in the Harry Potter universe that call muggles मगलू.

Comment: @JAD Okay, thanks for clearing it up. Actually yes, the word "मगलू" is mostly restricted to the translated books and movies. The Indian wizard community comprises of mostly youngsters who laugh at the mention of this word. They stick to "muggles". In fact, most online conversations (forums and fandom sites based) surrounding HP take place in English here in India. And even while conversing face-to-face in Hindi, we tend to use the official English terms for all things that are part of the HP world (spells, places, objects, names of the houses etc).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is just speculation on my part... but hear me out:

Since it's not actually an english word (Unless you consider it's root as [1920's New Orleans slang for a joint](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/muggle) and/or hot chocolate.) but rather a wizard world word I'd think that most countries would have a local word derived from olde wizarde or high wiz (or whatever the spell language is called) such as Muggle in English, Mugglare in Swedish and मगलू in Hindi (as Abhi stated).

Some communities could try and mark their uniqueness and standing apart from the other wizarding world by making up words (such as the americans with their slang word "no-maj") but the word "Muggle" would still be recognizeable by them.

Answer (score -1):

In Germany it is written: "Muggel" 
It is pronounced the same way, just with a deeper "u" and the double "g" is kinda quick.

Interesting topic though.

Comment: Do you have any references to support this? Preferably from HP universe?

Comment: @NogShine It’s from the official German translation of the books (and movies). But presumably that’s not what you’re asking about.